# Can a derived class have a constructor that is not in the base class in C++?

Tags: c++, class, oop, inheritance

Say I have a base class:

```
class Animal
{
public:
    Animal(double length, double height); 
    virtual ~Animal(); 

private:
    fLength;
    fHeight;
};
```

The constructor sets `fLength = length` and `fHeight = height`.

I have a derived class `Fish` which works fine.

But say I have a derived class `Cat` which has another property `fLegs` which needs to be set in the constructor. A fish does not have legs so it does not make sense for the Animal base class to have the property `fLegs`.

Can a constructor for Cat be created like:

`Cat(double length, double height, double Legs)` ?

I have tried this but an error comes up saying there is no matching function call to Animal.

Is there any way I can get around this without making the Fish have an fLegs property and setting it to 0 for the Fish?

Comment: Object-oriented programming should not work like this. Don't think of it as a way to compose properties. Think of it as defining a common interface for different operations. In this case, think of an operation common to all animals your program needs to support, e.g. `virtual void MakeNoise()`.

Comment: Hi, I do have common methods in the animal class as well which are inherited by the derived classes.

Comment: What data members should be in the classes is determined by how those classes implement the virtual functions. The base class often doesn't have any data members at all.

Comment: But I need the data members to be set in the constructors and all of the Animals will have a length and height so it makes sense.

Comment: As I said, object-oriented programming is not about what animals have but about what they do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Example:

```
class Animal
{
public:
    Animal(double length, double height) : fLength(length), fHeight(height) {}
    virtual ~Animal(){}; 

private:
    double fLength;
    double fHeight;
};

class Cat : public Animal
{
 public:
    Cat(double length, double height, double Legs) : Animal(length, height), fLegs(Legs) {}
 private:
    double fLegs;
};

int main(void)
{
    Cat(1,2,4);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: On second thought, answer updated! Good question @Oceanescence, +1 ;)

Comment: Thank you very much, so it isn't bad practice?

Comment: No, it makes sense for a derived class to have more data members of the base class! ;)

Comment: That's what I thought!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below. First initialize the base class constructor. Then derived class variables.

```
class Cat : public Animal
{
public:
    Cat(double length, double height, double legs) : Animal(length, height), fLength(legs)
    {
    } 

private:
   double flegs;
};
```

Comment: How is that different from my answer? =)

Comment: When I answer that your answer not visible. After I post the answer I saw yours,. Peace :D